# Generate all possible combinations in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, combinatorics

I have **one** table *Ingredients* with column *Name*:

```
Name
________
Cheese
Beans
Potato
etc
```

I want to display all possible combinations of those values like (cheese, beans) (cheese, potato), (beans, potato), etc in **two** columns. Is this possible?

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a self-join:

```
select t1.name name1, t2.name name2
from ingredients t1
inner join ingredients t2 on t2.name > t1.name
```

The inequality condition is there to ensure that we do not generate "mirror" records (like "cheese/beans" vs "beans/cheese").

If you want the mirror records, change that to `t2.name <> t1.name`.

If you also want "duplicate" records (like "cheese/cheese"), then use a `cross join` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Use a cross join:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Name
FROM yourTable t1
CROSS JOIN yourTable t2
WHERE t1.Name <> t2.Name;   -- use t1.Name < t2.Name if you don't want
                            -- a given pair appearing in reverse
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

This will generate all possible combinations of names, with the only restriction being that we don't report the same name twice as a pair.

Comment: in the demo, I see that you used union all to select those 3 values. but what if I have 100 values? Can I use union all on them?

Comment: @AbaiBaidyldaev I never used union anywhere...are you sure this comment doesn't belong under another answer?  `:-/`

Comment: Correct, they are table aliases.

Comment: could I, instead of writing t1.Name, write Name AS t1, Name AS t2?

Comment: Yes...but using `AS` is optional on SQL Server.  On some other databases, such as Access, it can be required.

Answer (score 4):

Use a self join

```
select i1.ingredient, i2.ingredient
from ingredients i1 join
     ingredients i2
     on i1.ingredient < i2.ingredient;
```

For four ingredients, this will return 6 rows, of all possible pairs but with each pair appearing only once.

Note:  This assumes that you do not want duplicates.  If you want *all* pairs, where the same ingredient can be in both columns in either order, then use `cross join`:

```
select i1.ingredient, i2.ingredient
from ingredients i1 cross join
     ingredients i2;
```

Answer (score 0):

A cross join would give you what you want.

```
FROM tableName t1
CROSS JOIN tableName t2;
```

A cross join gives you all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it in many ways. I would go for cross join as already suggested as this looks clearer in my opinion.
You can also join the table with itself where the name is not equal.

```
declare @t table (name varchar(50))

insert into @t
values('a'),('b'),('c'), ('d'), ('e'), ('f')

select * from @t t1 join @t t2
on t1.name <> t2.name
```